# How to assign css font family to $scope variable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**This is my controller**

```
$scope.fonts = [
    {
        "fontName":"Bamini"
    },
    {
        "fontName": "Monotype Corsiva"
    }
]
```

**This is my HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Select Font</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectFont" ng-options="font.fontName for font in fonts"></select>
       </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <textarea class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="Address" cols="40" rows="5" ng-style="{'font-family':selectFont.fontName}"></textarea>
        </div>
</div>
<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-6 col-xs-offset-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 " ng-click="AddUser(Address)">Add</button>
```

The above is my coding. I am trying to Select a font from the font dropdown and the font applies to the textarea using `ng-style="{'font-family':selectFont.fontName}"`

I want to save the same font style in db. can you tell me how to do this. As of now the style changes back to normal in the controller itself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to use Sass and assign variable font stacks.

Example:

//styles.scss

```
$font-stack: Open Sans, sans-serif;
$font-stack-alt: Source Sans Pro, sans-serif;

.example-class{
    font-family: $font-stack;
}
```

//example.component.html

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
  <textarea class="form-control example-class" type="text" ng-model="Address" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
```